How to properly configure Python to use system-level Certificates (windows) behind a Forced VPN (zscaler)?
I've recently started working within a large organization that requires all computers to be behind a forced VPN (zscaler). This setup has caused several issues when using multiple Python libraries and even when installing packages from remote sources, such as PyTorch with CUDA.
Here are the main issues we're encountering:

SSL Connection Errors: These errors arise because Python is not using
the system-level certificates.
Package Installation Failures: Particularly with packages like pytorch with CUDA, which require secure connections.

Some steps taken so far:

We tried to mitigate some of these issues by using the pip-system-certs package, which helps Python use the system certificates for pip installations
We encountered persistent issues with libraries like urllib3 and certifi, which do not fetch the proper certificates.
As a workaround, we manually exported the certificate from the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) and replaced the certificate that certifi was using

This workaround is not ideal mostly because we would have to do it for every virtual environment and every time the cert changes.
Is there a more elegant and streamlined solution for ensuring that Python uses the system-level certificates behind a forced VPN like zscaler? Ideally, I would like to:

Avoid manual certificate replacement steps.
Have a solution that works across different Python libraries and tools.
Possibly configure the system or Python environment to automatically use the correct
certificates

As more python developers join the team we really need a streamlined solution for this.

It's a far shot, but I believe the VPN is not the issue in itself. Everything that goes through it should be encapsulated. At best it should look like you popped out of somewhere else on the web. Did they happen to setup a proxy by the same occasion? Do you have --proxy settings for conda or pip? When you don't have access to the standard DNS, in a corporate environment, you might have to use a company hosted DSN with no access to the outside world. When communicating with internal servers, you will need to provide self-signed certs as .PEM chains. Is any of this related to your situation?

The comment by Florian above completely ignores the fact the OP is talking about ZSCALER. ZSCALER is effectively a Man in the middle attack as all requests get tunneled through a proxy and the certificate signing provided by the endpoint is replaced by the ZSCALER signing, and therefore need Zscaler root certificates recognized as trusted by individual applications. I sympathize for the OP, apps like python are a pain to get working properly with Zscaler.
